# Submenu Backcolor is not covering the entire text

Tags: html, css, asp.net, menu, submenu

I am not able to get the backcolor to be over the text for my submenus ... Here is a snapshot
[image]
My code follows:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu1" runat="server" orientation="Horizontal" CssClass="menusetting" BorderColor="#0070C0" BorderStyle="Solid" Font-Names="Arabic Typesetting" DisappearAfter="20000" Font-Size="Large">
    <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#999999" Width="100%" />
    <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor = "#FF99FF" Width="100%" />
    <DynamicMenuItemStyle BackColor = "#66CCFF" Width="100%" />
        <Items>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav1" Text="Home" Value="0"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav2" Target="_blank" Text="TAU Realtime Trading Account" Value="10"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav3" Text="Create Trial Account" Value="Create Trial Account"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Log on" Value="Log on" NavigateUrl="Nav4"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav5" Text="Contact Us" Value="9997"></asp:MenuItem>
            <asp:MenuItem Text="Product Overview" Value="Product Overview">
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav6" Target="_blank" Text="Kaizen (Trade Setup)" Value="30"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav7" Target="_blank" Text="TAU Presentation" Value="9995"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav8" Text="ULTRA Elements" Value="10" Target="_blank"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav9" Text="ULTRA Events" Value="20" Target="_blank"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav10" Text="ULTRA Options" Value="40"></asp:MenuItem>
                    <asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="Nav11" Target="_blank" Text="ULTRA Presentation" Value="9996"></asp:MenuItem>
            </asp:MenuItem>
        </Items>
    </asp:Menu>
```

CSS is below:

```
.menusetting
{
    float: right !important;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is likely due to the `float` property, which changes how elements flow and are sized by the browser.

Floats are generally not best practices these days for anything other than reflowing text around an image or other element. There's almost certainly another way to position your menu that won't cause this problem.

Comment: I removed the float and the background color is still only on part of the text